# jQuery plugin works on localhost but not when I publish it to the server

Tags: jquery, fancybox, localhost

this is first time using jQuery so I apologize if this is a naive question. I'm designing a website for this class at my school and I'm using Fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ . It works like a charm on my localhost (using MAMP), but when I publish it to my school's server, it doesn't work anymore. When I click on the image, it just opens up the bigger version of the image in a new page.

I've tried it in different browsers and computers. I've quadruple checked the file paths and everything checks out. The paths on the server are identical to the ones on my local directory. I've tried relocating the jquery scripts to the head and that didn't work either.

I'm also using another jquery plug called flexslider, but that's on a totally different page. The link to my site is http://nation1.aisites.com/imd311/portfolio/work.html .

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code, or a link to your site. It's hard to diagnose a problem you can't see. It does sound like you've not uploaded all the jQuery files though. Do you get any errrors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the link is inside the question

Comment: Error: TypeError: $(".fancybox").fancybox is not a function
this is the error which is displaying in function. are you sure you include fancybox scripts. can you show the mark up here

Comment: @PartyNation: there are a lot of 404 on that page

Comment: @Ravi: of course it is not a function - there are 404s there )

Comment: The requested URL `/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6` was not found on this server.

Comment: jquery.fancybox.pack.js is on the server though.

Comment: ?v=2.0.6 is not apart of the file name though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting a 404 for several scripts in your page, including `jquery.fancybox.pack.js`. Check your browser's debug console.

Answer (score 2):

The requested `URL /source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6` was not found on this server. this the error we are getting. make sure that you included all your  `resource files(CSS, images, JS)` files in Correct path.

1. you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug.
2. You can use google CDN for Jquery [CDN For Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the URL of the remote server when you include jQuery or other plugins, not the local one or, use a relative links, or use direct link from Google. Your problem is related to the incorrect file inclusion path, try to solve it like this:

For example:

```
//Remote
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourserver.com/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
//Google
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
//Relative links
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

**Important note**: you need to include jQuery FIRST, before any other plugins in order everything to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script link from

```
/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6
```

to

```
/imd311/portfolio/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6
```

i presume your localhost does not reflect your server env

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much. I knew it had something to do with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Path to the fancybox.js is not Correct. it shows `<script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.6"></script>` after rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is getting old but I had the same problem and manage to solve it.

My website use HTTPS and the references to my jquery file and the fancybox's files were in HTTP. The server blocked all the files imported from HTTP links so fancybox wasn't working.

So just replace http:// by https:// in each file's path.